# How to modify H.264 header such that the decoder will repeat the previous coded frames for certain frames?

Tags: h.264

How to modify H.264 header such that the decoder will repeat the previous coded frames for certain frames?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a *Dummy* frame which has picture start-code, followed by 1 (or more) slice start-code. Within slice you can declare all Macroblock as skipped with Motion vector = (0,0). 
The picture type and references can be previous picture. The temporal reference should be incremented appropriately. This will force decoder to copy-paste the past picture as it is.